# asp.net web application with an interface to dynamically select the data providers listed in a dropdown

Tags: asp.net

I was searching for a sample asp.net web application with an interface to dynamically select the data providers which is listed in a dropdown and load or connect to the selected dataprovider

I got a sample : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2850/Dynamically-access-a-database-through-a-Web-Applic

Since I am using VS2010,I searched for similar other samples..But I dint get anyone..

Please help me to get a sample web application with such an interface.

Comment: I have the same issue.. Please help me too